# How to fill PrimeNG DataTable with Array<Object> in Angular2?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have an array of objects (called *devices*) which I get from an API during a POST method.
When I try to fill it in a simple html table, it works:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let property of devices[0] | keys">{{property.key}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let device of devices">
      <td *ngFor="let property of device | keys">{{property.value == null ? '---' : property.value.toString()}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I also use custom pipe to display key and value of each property of an object:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'keys' })
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args: string[]): any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        keys.push({ key: key, value: value[key] });
      }
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

But when I try to do the same with PrimeNG DataTable, it doesn't display anything:

```
<p-dataTable var="device" [value]="devices" sortMode="multiple">
   <p-column *ngFor="let property of device | keys" field="{{property.value == null ? '---' : property.value.toString()}}" header="{{property.key}}" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Could you create a plunker or github repo? That would make things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem was that I didn't fill in the headers, so PrimeNG didn't know what to do with the data.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="devices">
  <p-column *ngFor="let header of headers" [field]="header.field" [header]="header.header"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

And here's the filling of headers taken from the first object of array (all objects in my array have the same properties, just with different values):

```
public headers = [];

FillHeaders(devices) {
  for (let property in devices[0]) {
    if (devices[0].hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      this.headers.push({ field: property, header: property });
    }
  }
}
```